# Dividing two select statements to get a decimal

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to divide two separate COUNT statements to get a decimal. Right now, the output returns '0', but the answer should be 0.073

Here is my code:

```
SELECT(
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM (
    SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) as "num_purchases"
    FROM loan
    GROUP BY user_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) >2
) AS repeat)
/ (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) FROM loan) AS "percentage"
```

Comment: You must explicitly cast both results as float, so the division won't be integer

Comment: With reference to the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/divide-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 `Divisions returns the data type of the argument with the higher precedence.`. Since both are integer, it returns an integer

Comment: Ideally not a float, as that gives stranger results. Decimal is better.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server does integer division, so `1/2` is `0` rather than `0.5`.  I just multiply by 1.0:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) * 1.0 / (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) FROM loan) AS "percentage" 
FROM (SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) as "num_purchases"
      FROM loan
      GROUP BY user_id
      HAVING COUNT(*) >2
     ) l
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also cast any of them to FLOAT.

```
SELECT CAST(COUNT(*) AS FLOAT)  
        / 
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) FROM loan) AS "percentage" 
FROM (SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) as "num_purchases"
      FROM loan
      GROUP BY user_id
      HAVING COUNT(*) >2
     ) l
```

Comment: Ideally not a float, as that gives stranger results. Decimal is better.